# Setup full eos node

Tags: nodeos, rpc, explorer

Is there any way to setup eos node as full node for using it like some tracker (I mean for getting balance or transaction history by public address without importing private keys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can follow this tutorial https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet without adding the producer part. You will be a full node connected to the MainNet and you will be able to play with your node :)

Comment: Tnx for answer. About `without adding the producer part` you mean missing adding producer name and keypair?

Comment: yeah, and actually what really matters is the `plugin = eosio::producer_plugin` -- it adds the production functionality.